# SOAP PHP - last request does not return last request

Tags: php, soap

I try to send the following request with $soap->__call("CreateAuftrag", array($request));

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:tem='http://tempuri.org/' xmlns:xps='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XPService'>
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:CreateAuftrag>         
         <tem:pSecurityToken>XXXXXXXX</tem:pSecurityToken>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:pAuftrag>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:ArtikelList>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <xps:wtxAuftragPositionWebShop>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xps:Anzahl>1</xps:Anzahl>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xps:Bezeichnung>Testosan</xps:Bezeichnung>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xps:Einheit>STK</xps:Einheit>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xps:Menge>1</xps:Menge>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xps:PZN>0751858</xps:PZN>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xps:PositionKommentar>TESTIMPORT</xps:PositionKommentar>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xps:Preis>123.45</xps:Preis>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xps:Status>0</xps:Status>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xps:Steuerfaktor>0</xps:Steuerfaktor>
               </xps:wtxAuftragPositionWebShop>
            </xps:ArtikelList>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:Datum>?</xps:Datum>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:Kommentar>AUTOMATISCHER IMPORT VOM ONLINE SHOP</xps:Kommentar>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:Kunde>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:Abteilung>?</xps:Abteilung>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:EMail>o@o.o</xps:EMail>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:Firma>?</xps:Firma>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:GeschlechtKz>?</xps:GeschlechtKz>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:Gruppe>?</xps:Gruppe>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:LiefLandKz>?</xps:LiefLandKz>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:LiefOrt>?</xps:LiefOrt>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:LiefPlz>?</xps:LiefPlz>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:LiefStrasse>?</xps:LiefStrasse>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:Nachname>MEINEapo.at</xps:Nachname>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:Personcode>?</xps:Personcode>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:RechLandKz>?</xps:RechLandKz>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:RechOrt>?</xps:RechOrt>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:RechPlz>?</xps:RechPlz>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:RechStrasse>?</xps:RechStrasse>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:SyncKz>?</xps:SyncKz>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:Titel>?</xps:Titel>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xps:Vorname>?</xps:Vorname>
            </xps:Kunde>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:LieferMethode>?</xps:LieferMethode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:Nummer>?</xps:Nummer>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:Status>?</xps:Status>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:TrackingID>?</xps:TrackingID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:TrackingURL>?</xps:TrackingURL>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:Wert>0</xps:Wert>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xps:ZahlungMethode>?</xps:ZahlungMethode>
         </tem:pAuftrag>
      </tem:CreateAuftrag>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>";
```

I get as result with

echo "LAST REQUEST:********************\r\n". $soap->__getLastRequest();

the following result:

LAST REQUEST:********************

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">env:Bodyns1:CreateAuftrag/</env:Body></env:Envelope>

Can this be correct? Shouldn't there be the whole request?

Regards,
Gunther

Should return the whole xml-request I suppose?

Comment: This is absolutely correct. On the other hand this means, that your request is not correct. What 's the soap response and what 's the content of `$request`?